# W3C validation error for use of <html> in quoted string: 'document type does not allow element "html" here'

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I receive the following error using HTML in a quoted string:

> Error Line 63, Column 39: document type does not allow element "html" here
>
> ```
> mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title>mydiv</title>");
> ```
>
> The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

Am I doing something wrong or is the W3C validator giving bad results?

Comment: as far as I know, you are only allowed to write the content of the body via Javascript. Not the whole html document.

Comment: Hi, Did you try with simple quotes : mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>mydiv</title>');
@Wavemaster: In case you're writing the current page, yes. But in case you're writing a popup, I think should be authorized

Comment: @Wavemaster — It's writing a new document to a new window

Comment: @lookfire — That wouldn't make any difference

Comment: I find it interesting that I can not put <> around html in my question.

Comment: single quotes make no difference

Comment: @MikeD — Stackoverflow uses Markdown for input. You can either type `&gt;` or use code ticks if you want to express those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't get that error in an HTML document.

Presumably, therefore, you are writing XHTML.

My first piece of advice is: **Don't**. XHTML is usually more trouble than it is worth. **Use HTML 5 instead and that won't be invalid**.

---

If you need to use XHTML then see the specification:

Differences from HTML: [Script and Style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8)

> In XHTML, the script and style elements are declared as having #PCDATA
>   content. As a result, `<` and `&` will be treated as the start of markup,
>   and entities such as `&lt;` and `&amp;` will be recognized as entity
>   references by the XML processor to `<` and `&` respectively. Wrapping the
>   content of the script or style element within a `CDATA` marked section
>   avoids the expansion of these entities.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> <![CDATA[
> ... unescaped script content ...
> ]]>
> </script>
> ```

HTML compatibility guidelines: [Embedded Style Sheets and Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4):

> Use external style sheets if your style sheet uses `<` or `&` or `]]>` or
>   `> --`. **Use external scripts if your script uses `<` or `&` or `]]>` or `--`.** Note that XML parsers are permitted to silently remove the contents of
>   comments. Therefore, the historical practice of "hiding" scripts and
>   style sheets within "comments" to make the documents backward
>   compatible is likely to not work as expected in XML-based user agents.

Comment: Thanks.  Both solutions offered correct the W3C errors.